# Connect two internal networks in one network

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, virtual-machines, tunnel

I have two servers `A` and `B`. Server `A` with device `ens3` and address `10.1.0.171` and server `B` with device `ens3` and address `10.1.0.253`.

I want to setup on server `A` and server `B` networks `10.2.0.0/24`, up vm instances, and I want access from vm from server `A` to vm from server `B`.

I tried to create on server `A` and server `B` bridge `br0`; add interfaces `ens3` to `br0`, and up gretap tunnel. But I don't understand how can I connect gretap tunnel to local networks `10.2.0.0/24`.

How can I implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that you split your 10.2.0.0/24 network into 2 distinct networks 10.2.0.0/25 and 10.2.0.128/25, one internal for each server, and then use IP in IP encapsulation to route the packets between those two networks.

You can find details how to do this in https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.tunnel.ip-ip.html.

Comment: The same question. How can I connect tunnel to internal network?

Comment: @e42d3 I think I misunderstood your need. I tried a second answer; I will delete this one if you confirm my second answer fits your need better.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that you split your 10.2.0.0/24 network into 2 distinct networks 10.2.0.0/25 and 10.2.0.128/25, first one internal to server A, second one internal to server B.

Then, you can add a route from server A to server B’s network:

```
ip route add 10.2.0.128/25 via 10.1.0.253
```

and from server B to server A’s network:

```
ip route add 10.2.0.0/25 via 10.1.0.171
```

Of course, you also have to enable IP packet forwarding:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Note that I assume that servers are on the same network. If there is a router between them, you need to set up some tunneling, like IP in IP or GRE between the servers, and route through the tunnel.